# Can we use excel functions in reactjs or jquery?

Tags: reactjs, excel-formula

I need to use all excel functions which return the calculation result. eg. "AverageIf","Decimal".Is there any API or something cdn file which returns all excel functions?

I will be very grateful if someone has information regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a NPM module called [hot-formula-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hot-formula-parser) which may be the thing you're looking for.

Example:

```js
import { Parser } from 'hot-formula-parser';

const parser = new Parser();
parser.parse('SUM(1, 6, 7)');
```

If you need a list of all formulas supported by the module you can just do:

```js
import { SUPPORTED_FORMULAS } from 'hot-formula-parser';
```

Comment: Thanks it really helpful for me and it works fine for all excel functions in reactjs.

Comment: I also need LOOKUP functions eg. "FIRST(ARRAY(1,2,3)) // returns 1"   and STATISTICAL functions .eg. "COUNTNUMBERS(ARGS2ARRAY(1, 3, "pear", "5", "pear"))". Any help for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I only know of this module, but the documentation mentions callbacks for cell values, maybe you could look into that.

Comment: Ok no problem Thanks for your help.